# How to download a file to the default storage location using HTTP Response from a given URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, filesystems, mapping

I am new to C# and reactjs and am stuck in this conundrum. I am using a function to download the images from url into my local file. Doing that I am specifying the file path.

The function is this:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("GetImages")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetImages()
        {
            Somewhere();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {

                var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tsl-coil-qlty- 
                           monitoring-dev.appspot.com/o/1a60ce3b-eddf-4e72-b2af-b6e99873e926? 
                           alt=media&token=61399a02-1009-4bb9-ad89-d1235df900e4";
                webClient.DownloadFile(url, @"D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image4.jpg");
            }
        
            return Ok();

        }
```

The problem is I am specifying a file path in the function. Can it be made so that I do not need to specify the file path and it will get downloaded to a default location.

Please help also please let me know if this can be done with HTTP Response?

The file path that  I am giving here is "D:\CQMS_Images_JPEG\image4.jpg"

Comment: Why just not use configuration and set this up there ? Then, use the options pattern to retrieve the value.

More information over here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Can you give an example in the code I dont quite get it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue -

1. You can create an entry inside configuration section in web config that will have location information and use that value inside DownloadFile function instead of hard code path.
   [image]

[image]

2. You can create a folder inside your application and use the Server.MapPath to get that location. e.g - You have folder name abc then you will get exact path by -
   [image]